# $GL2(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$

Tags: group-theory

For the following, I am not sure $A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ needs to proven to be a group. Also, I am not sure what the identity is for $GL2(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, is the multiplication the operation to use?Thanks

The general linear group $GL2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $2\times2$ invertible matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. Viewing $GL2(\mathbb{R})$ as a subset of the set $A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ of all bijective maps $\mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$, show that $GL2(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$.

Here is my proof so far:

$A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is the set of all bijective maps $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ which includes the identity $e(x)=x, e:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ under composition.

The set $A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is closed under binary operation of composition.  Let $f,g\in A(\mathbb{R}^{2})\ f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\ $ and $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ then $f\circ g: \mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ by the definition of functions f and g, and by definition of composition.
$A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is associative over composition. Let  $f,g,h\in A(\mathbb{R}^{2})\ f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\ g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\ h:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ then $f\circ g\circ h: \mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $(f\circ g)\circ h = f\circ (g\circ h)$ since composition of functions is associative.
$A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ has inverses for all its elements over composition. This is so because all bijective functions have an inverse. $\forall f\in A(\mathbb{R}^{2})\ \exists f^{-1}\in A(\mathbb{R}^{2}) \backepsilon f\circ f^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ f = e$.
In conclusion $A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is a group under composition.

Next we prove $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$.
By its definition $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})\subset A(\mathbb{R}^{2})$. This is so because $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ contains invertable $2\times2$ matrices and this set over inversion creates a bijective map.
$GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ with the composition operation creates a binary operation. Let $f\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})\ f:\mathbb{R}_{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_{2}\ f(x)=x^{-1}\ \forall x\ det(x)\neq0$. Similarly, we have $g(x)=x^{-1}$. Consequently, $f\circ g=x$. So this is a binary operation.
$GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ under the composition is associative: $(f\circ g)\circ h=f\circ (g\circ h)=x^{-1}$.

$GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ with the composition operation has $e=I$
as the identity element.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: will do, I am new to Latex.